# Thermodynamics in a closed room - Why does the stale smell depend on Temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why does the stale smell disappears in a crowded room if you cool it via air-condition ? What's the physics ?

Comment: thumbs downed. fresh air is added to keep CO2, odour etc lowest.

Comment: What does this have to do with thermodynamics?

Comment: A clarification:
- If you use the air-condition as a fan (such the thermostat Temp is higher than the room temp) than the stale smell still remains. In this case the air-condition still works the same way with regard to fresh air/mold/ Etc. 
- If you set the air-condition to cool the room (set the min temp the air-condition can support) the stale smell disappears. 
- To my understanding this is due to the thermodynamics of the in-door air but I do not know the physics behind it.

Comment: A clarification: - If you use the air-condition as a fan (such the thermostat Temp is higher than the room temp) than the stale smell still remains. In this case the air-condition still works the same way with regard to fresh air/mold/ Etc. - If you set the air-condition to cool the room (set the min temp the air-condition can support) the stale smell disappears. - To my understanding this is due to the thermodynamics of the in-door air but I do not know the physics behind it

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with thermodynamics – the stale smell is due to certain molecules or mould spores floating in the air. Putting fresh air into the room, and removing the old air, displaces these floating molecules and removes the smell.

Comment: A typical air conditioner doesn't add fresh air, though, it just cools down the air that's already in the room. (See this diagram, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Air_conditioning_unit-en.svg)

Comment: I think it can be expected for these to also incorporate an air filter somewhere...

Comment: @Nathan: Many air conditioners have a fresh air bleed.  They also have filters and cause water to condense out.

Comment: A clarification:
- If you use the air-condition as a fan (such the thermostat Temp is higher than the room temp) than the stale smell still remains. In this case the air-condition still works the same way with regard to fresh air/mold/ Etc. 
- If you set the air-condition to cool the room (set the min temp the air-condition can support) the stale smell disappears. 
- To my understanding this is due to the thermodynamics of the in-door air but I do not know the physics behind it.